# Show response time in Grafana using Prometheus

Tags: histogram, prometheus, grafana, promql

I have a Histogram of values, very similar to how ASP.NET Core does it for their duration of HTTP requests.
[image]
My histogram is the following: `reservations_api_processing_time`. I have several key/value pairs in there, and I want to build a dashboard to show the processing time for each key. For example, in the above screenshot, I have two keys `search_statistics="load-statistics-InHouse"` and `basic_search="first-page"`.

I tried several things, such as:
`sum by (le) (rate(reservations_api_processing_time_bucket{search_statistics="load-statistics-InHouse"}[30s]))`
Or
`reservations_api_processing_time_bucket{search_statistics="load-statistics-InHouse"}`
Or
`histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(rate(reservations_api_processing_time_bucket{search_statistics="load-statistics-InHouse"}[$__rate_interval])) by (le))`

But neither really shows me the values as I want them to be seen.. I don't mind using Histogram or Heatmap as panel, either work for me, as long as I can see the actual processing time history.

My goal is to visualize the amount of time it took to process given a time period. For example, if I had 5 executions, and the processing time took [100, 200, 300, 400, 500] in ms, I want to be able to see all 5 executions as they are in my graph.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should return 95th [percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) of processing time for requests performed during the last hour (see `1h` lookbehind window in square brackets), grouped by any additional labels other than `le`, which exist at `reservations_api_processing_time` histogram:

```
histogram_quantile(0.95, rate(reservations_api_processing_time_bucket[1h]))
```

See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#histogram) for more details about Prometheus histograms